# After brew install varnish on OSX where can I find configuration file to change DAEMON_OPTS

Tags: homebrew, osx-yosemite, varnish

After brew install varnish I would like to chenge some options in config file for example DAEMON_OPTS unfortunetlly I can't find this file.
In linux it is in folders:

- Ubuntu: /etc/default/varnish
- CentOS 6.x: /etc/sysconfig/varnish
- CentOS 7.x: /etc/varnish/varnish.params

Where can I find it on OSX?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am not familiar with the **varnish** package myself, but if you run:

```
brew info varnish
```

it tells you a load of ancillary info, and amongst that, it tells you how to manually start it and reveals the config file location:

```
/usr/local/sbin/varnishd -n /usr/local/var/varnish -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:8080 -F
```

So, I assume the file you are looking for is:

```
/usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

Note that `brew info varnish` (as shown above) doesn’t require you to have that package installed.

---

If you do have it installed, you can use the following to see all the files belonging to that package, and thereby find the config file:

```
brew ls varnish
```

Note that `brew info varnish` doesn't always tell you all files, to be maximally sure of getting a complete list of files associated with a package, use the `-verbose` flag:

```
brew ls varnish -verbose
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/.bottle/etc/varnish/default.vcl
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/.brew/varnish.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishadm
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishhist
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishlog
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishncsa
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishstat
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishtest
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/bin/varnishtop
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/ChangeLog
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/homebrew.mxcl.varnish.plist
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/cache/cache.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/cache/cache_backend.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/cache/cache_director.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/cache/cache_filter.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/common/com_params.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/common/common.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/common/common_vsm.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/miniobj.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/acct_fields_bereq.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/acct_fields_req.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/backend_poll.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/ban_vars.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/bo_flags.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/boc_state.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/body_status.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/cli_cmds.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/debug_bits.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/feature_bits.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/h2_error.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/h2_frames.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/h2_settings.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/h2_stream.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/http_headers.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/http_response.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/locks.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/obj_attr.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/oc_exp_flags.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/oc_flags.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/params.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/req_body.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/req_flags.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/sess_attr.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/sess_close.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/steps.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/symbol_kind.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vcc_types.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vcl_returns.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vhd_fsm.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vhd_fsm_funcs.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vhd_return.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vhp_huffman.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vhp_static.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vrt_stv_var.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vsc_levels.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vsl_tags.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/vsl_tags_http.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/tbl/waiters.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/vapi_options.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/voptget.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/vsc.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/vsc_int.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/vsl.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/vsl_int.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vapi/vsm.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vas.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vav.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vbm.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vcl.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vcli.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vcs.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vdef.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vmod_abi.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vqueue.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vre.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vrnd.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vrt.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vrt_obj.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vsa.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vsb.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vsha256.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vtcp.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vtim.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vut.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/vut_options.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/include/varnish/waiter/waiter.h
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/libvarnishapi.1.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/libvarnishapi.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/pkgconfig/varnishapi.pc
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_blob.so
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_directors.so
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_purge.so
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_std.so
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/lib/varnish/vmods/libvmod_vtc.so
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/LICENSE
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/README.rst
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/sbin/varnishd
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/aclocal/varnish-legacy.m4
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/aclocal/varnish.m4
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/doc/varnish/builtin.vcl
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/doc/varnish/example.vcl
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishadm.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishd.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishhist.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishlog.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishncsa.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishstat.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishtest.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man1/varnishtop.1
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man3/vmod_blob.3
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man3/vmod_directors.3
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man3/vmod_purge.3
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man3/vmod_std.3
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man3/vmod_vtc.3
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man7/varnish-cli.7
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man7/varnish-counters.7
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man7/vcl.7
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man7/vsl-query.7
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man7/vsl.7
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/man/man7/vtc.7
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/varnish/vcl/devicedetect.vcl
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/varnish/vmodtool.py
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/share/varnish/vsctool.py
```

When **macOS** starts daemons via `launchd` and `launchctl` it generally uses a `plist` file to configure the options with which daemons should be started, so you may actually be looking for this file for setting daemon options:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/varnish/5.2.1/homebrew.mxcl.varnish.plist
```

which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.varnish</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/varnish/sbin/varnishd</string>
    <string>-n</string>
    <string>/usr/local/var/varnish</string>
    <string>-f</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl</string>
    <string>-s</string>
    <string>malloc,1G</string>
    <string>-T</string>
    <string>127.0.0.1:2000</string>
    <string>-a</string>
    <string>0.0.0.0:8080</string>
    <string>-F</string>
  </array>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local</string>
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/varnish/varnish.log</string>
  <key>StandardOutPath</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/varnish/varnish.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Thx for detailed answer :D